# using open cv to detect a rect

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, polygon

I am currently using opencv to try and detect the rect around each individual parking sign in a group of signs. Using "findContours" and "approxPolyDP" has gotten me close but I want consolidate the contours into a single rect. Using "boundingRect" has not worked since there are breaks in the shape.

Let me know if you have any advise on how to approach this problem.

Here is my code:

```python
image = cv2.imread(sign_directory)
# find all the 'red' shapes in the image
lower = np.array([0, 0, 110])
upper = np.array([100, 100, 250])
shapeMask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
# find the contours in the mask
(img, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(shapeMask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[This is the image it produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxrvP.png)

[I want to get something like this so that I can crop it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrKBs.jpg)

[This is the original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2UtV.jpg)

Comment: you want the external rect to be the only one drawn?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am just trying to draw the external rect for the red sign. I will eventually want the rect for the green sign too, but am not trying to do that here.

Comment: Can you please attach the original image as well ?

Comment: @ZdaR just uploaded the original image.

Comment: Would [opencv scene text detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/erfilter.html) be of any use here? I think that is trained exactly for that kind of text in wild detections ([python example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/textdetection.py))

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing each contour to `cv2.boundingRect()` you want to merge them all in a single array and then pass to that function, then you get the bounding box you need to crop. But before doing that you need to remove outliers/noise, the contours that are too far from the others.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Yes, I have been looking into merging the contours. Do you have any tips on the best way to approach this?